# Hiding folders inside root folder using htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my server I have the following folder structure and I want to display each folder project link without the folder name. How can I do this?

```
Root Folder
  -> Subfolder1
     -> Project folder 1
     -> Project folder 2
  -> Subfolder2
     -> Project folder 3
     -> Project folder 4
  -> Subfolder3
     -> Project folder 5
```

I want to display my project URL without the subfolder, ie:

```
www.domain.com/project folder 1
www.domain.com/project folder 2
etc....
```

Comment: if you do not want folder in URL then how you need URL?

Comment: How many different projects (and subfolders) do you have? Is there any naming pattern that links the subfolder with the project folder? Do you have access to the server config, or are you limited to just .htaccess?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Currently i have 3 subfolder and there will be multiple project inside each subfolders.There is no naming pattern and now I just want to limit via htaccess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the relationship between the project-folder and the sub-folder, ie. which sub-folder a particular project is in. If there is no pattern between project-folder and sub-folder and being restricted to .htaccess then I think you'll need to specify each rewrite manually.

You can *internally rewrite* all requests for the respective project to include the appropriate sub-folder.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^project-folder1.* /sub-folder1/$0 [L]
RewriteRule ^project-folder2.* /sub-folder1/$0 [L]
RewriteRule ^project-folder3.* /sub-folder2/$0 [L]
# etc...
```

Note that this is an internal rewrite, not an external redirect, the URL in the address bar won't show the sub-folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It works for me.I just made little bit changes.                                   

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wordpress/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wordpress/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wordpress/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/codeigniter/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/codeigniter/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeigniter/$1 [L,NC]

Comment: Please advice if i make any mistakes in my code.Although It works fine.

Comment: That is quite a different method, but yes, it should work OK. That is certainly better if you have lots of projects and avoids having to update the .htaccess file when you add more projects, providing they are within one of a few top-level subfolders. However, it is perhaps less efficient since every request will be processed.

Comment: Now this is not working in case of sub domains.The projects are moved to sub domain like demo.domain.com.But now the project files cannot access without direct path.Please advice any solution.

Comment: @AlisonsBg If the projects are now on subdomains then you are not going to be able to _internally rewrite_ `www.example.com/demo` to `demo.example.com` - if that is what you mean? You will need to _externally redirect_ the request. But presumably the purpose of using subdomains is to have them visible anyway?